# Correct approach to creating a new Salesforce DX project and pulling from GIT

Tags: salesforcedx, git

I am learning Git with Salesforce DX. I learned how to use the terminal for pulling, pushing, committing etc. I know that Salesforce DX has a handy UI to do this without having to use the terminal, which is pretty neat.

As a Salesforce developer, when I get assigned to a project, get my access to a repo to pull data from main into my local repository, what is the correct approach? I tried doing this:

1. Open Salesforce DX
2. Create new Project
3. Git init
4. Connect to Git repo
5. Pull data from master
6. Error:

> ```
>   error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
>     .eslintignore
>     .forceignore
>     .gitignore
>     .husky/pre-commit
>     .prettierignore
>     .prettierrc
>     README.md
>     config/project-scratch-def.json
>     force-app/main/default/aura/.eslintrc.json
>     force-app/main/default/lwc/.eslintrc.json
>     jest.config.js
>     package.json
>     scripts/apex/hello.apex
>     scripts/soql/account.soql
>     sfdx-project.json
>     Please move or remove them before you merge.
>     Aborting
> ```

Can you please point out my error?

Comment: Sounds like the repo is already set up as a project. Instead of creating a new project, just clone the existing project repo.

Comment: @PhilW I tried that but then I am not able to Authorize an Org and create Scratch Org. It requires me to create a project first. Any idea?

Comment: SalesforceDX is generally a reference to the Salesforce CLI (Command Line Input). It, in and of itself, does not have a UI and it can't be "opened". Perhaps you're referring to Microsoft's Visual Studio Code (which does have a GUI (Graphical User Interface), and has extensions to integrate with the Salesforce CLI). Authorizing an org and creating scratch orgs are completely independent from your Git repo.

Comment: @DerekF Okay, I will create separate question for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil W said, what worked for me was not to create a new SFDX Project at all, but since the sfdx-project.json was included in the Git repository, simply git init a repo, pull the repo from Git, then close Visual Studio Code and open it again. The project would not register after downloading the repo from the CLI, but after closing the IDE and opening it again, it would.